# NullPointerException on list.add

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at the `modelData.add(i, es)` method. I know from debugging that `es` isn't `null`. I'm really confused, thanks.

```
public class EventTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    //private int rowCount = 0;
    protected List<EventSeat> modelData;
    private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 3;
    private Event e;
    Event j = GUIpos.m;
    int i = 1;

public EventTableModel(Event e) {
    this.e = e;
    try {
        System.out.println(modelData);
        for (EventSeat es : e.getEventSeats()) {
            modelData.add(i, es);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (DataException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventTableModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `modelData` get initialized?

Comment: Where is `modelData` initialised? Shouldn't there be a `modelData = new ArrayList<EventSeat>();` somewhere?

Comment: holy crap, that's it I think....let me check

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to initialize a List to not get the `NullPointerException`.

```
protected List<EventSeat> modelData = new ArrayList<EventSeat>();
```

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
protected List<EventSeat> modelData = new ArrayList<EventSeat>();
```

Comment: Bonus points if you change this to match the other two answers; I don't think you can instantiate a `List` like that.

Answer (score 6):

On the first look, seems like modelData has not been instantiated. I would instantiate the modelData like:

```
protected List<EventSeat> modelData = new ArrayList<EventSeat>();
```

FYI.. In Java 7 there will be a new syntax you can use- `someObject?.doSomething();`

Comment: I don't think e.getEventSeats() returns null (or returns an iterator containing a nulll element). If that were the case the code would terminate at the start of the `for`.

Comment: Sure..wrote the solution in haste. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -1):

The modelData was not initialize.Try initialing it using the below snippet.

```
protected List<EventSeat> modelData=new ArrayList<>();
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer doesn't add anything that's not covered by other answers. You can upvote them if you agree with them. See also [answer].